# Advice on how to structure this data?

Tags: java, oop

I receive this data, it's over the network so need to cache it locally.

The data is in format:

```
Action (String)
    Direction (String)
        Frame (int)
            X,Y (Point or int,int)
```

The usage is basically:

```
Point myPoint = data.get(action).get(direction).get(frame);
myPoint.x; // do something with x and y
```

I tried a this huge hashmap type of structure:

```
HashMaP<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<int, Point>>>
```

it works, but ugly and prone to errors.

I also tried splitting it into Classes, which works; but needs a lot of housekeeping code.

Anyone know what this data structure called, maybe I can google it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with classes? What "house keeping" code is there?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with classes per say, I guess "house keeping" is the wrong word.  How would you structure/organize it, Action contains a Direction and Direction contains Hashmap<Int,Point>?

Comment: Before we can suggest a class hierarchy, you need to describe the relationship between each item and its parent. Can an `Action` have many `Direction`s etc?

Comment: `Action` will general be about 20, but can add more in future.  `Directions` will be limited to 5, doubtful to every change.  `Frames` will be between 1 and 20.  There is will one `Point` X and Y, maybe Z in future

Comment: @user1516346: define classes (a model). It's an object oriented language so this is the way to go...

Comment: There is no class hierarchy here, only object hierarchy (composition).

Answer (score 4):

implicit in "huge hashmap type of structure" is the relationship between entities:

- action is a String which indexes 'many' direction
- direction is a String which indexes 'many' frame
- frame is a number which indexes 'many' points
- Point is a structure

One simple approach might be to define a 'key' object containing 'action' 'direction' and 'frame' and use this in a Map structure e.g.

```
class PointKey {
    String action, direction;
    int frame;
    PointKey(String action, String direction, int frame { .. init etc etc }

...
```

depending on usage characteristics you will want either to override `hashCode` to provide some "reasonably" unique value based of the three-part key or else implement `Comparable` if you're expecting there to be a large amount of these values and you expect to be reading them more than writing them.

Then you define your `Map` thus:

```
Map<PointKey,Point> data = new HashMap<PointKey,Point>();
```

or

```
Map<PointKey,Point> data = new TreeMap<PointKey,Point>();
```

depending on which approach you have selected.

Another concern, if you are creating a large amount of these keys is the overhead of creating new keys to randomly access them, and in such a case you may like to use a flyweight e.g.

```
...
// PointKey instance that is retained and used again and again, purely for 'access' purposes
dataKey.setIdentifiers(myAction, myDirection, myFrame);
Point myPoint = data.get(dataKey)
```